# VARCHAR as Out parameter returns error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm learning about PL/SQL Stored Procedures and encountered numeric or value error.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(
   VARCHAROUT OUT VARCHAR
)AS 
   BEGIN
      VARCHAROUT := 'test test test';
END;
```

My Query:

```
DECLARE
   OUTOUT VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
   TEST_PROC(OUTOUT);
   :OUTOUT := OUTOUT;
END;
```

ERROR:

> Error report - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character
>   string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 8
>   06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>   *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>              occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>              assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>              attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>              declared NUMBER(2).
>   *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
>              that values do not violate constraints.

Comment: How and where is your `OUTOUT` bind variable defined? (The one prefixed with a colon when you assign it; having different names would be less confusing, though you don't need both the bind and local variable in this example.) Not really relevant, but is there a reason you're using `varchar` rather than `varchar2`?

Comment: @AlexPoole *"The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings."*

Comment: Reiterating what @AlexPoole asked: how is the bind variable `:OUTOUT` defined? Since the code we *can* see isn't the problem, it must be the code we *can't* see.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've posted. The error says it's *at line 8*, and neither of the blocks of code you posted has 8 lines in it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. it's fixed by just removing the :OUTOUT := OUTOUT; thanks so much